# How can I return the SECOND GREATEST value in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a `CASE` statement within an `ON` clause:

```
ON A.month = CASE WHEN (B.month = GREATEST(B.month)) 
             THEN B.month - 1  
             ELSE B.month 
             END
```

It will function until the year rolls over.

Is there a way to return the second GREATEST value instead of using `B.month - 1`?
Something similar to the Excel function `LARGE(*array*, 2)`?

Subqueries don't seem to work within `ON` clauses.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where is this `on` placed? The only place I know is `join` clause, where you cannot use any aggregation (because aggregation takes place after defining row source and filtering it). Also `greatest` is a row-level function which takes values of the same result row, not entire column, and returns the greatest value of its arguments. You should provide your query, sample data and desired output so someone will help you to adjust the query to suit your needs.

Comment: `B.month = GREATEST(B.month)` is always true.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I misinterpreted the GREATEST function.  I solved this with a workaround in the Table A.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following SQL to get second largest value:-

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT Coll, 
         row_number() over (order by Coll desc) as row_num
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) t
WHERE row_num = 2
```